# Best way to make a Multi Touch application

Tags: wpf, windows, flash, touch, multi-touch

I need to make a multi touch application for a real state display centre.  With buttons and maps and floor plans. And the application will be running on Windows 8.1 0 on a 42 inch screen. I want to know what would be the best technology to make this kind application ? Flash or WPF ?

Does Action script has events for the buttons ?

Answer (score 0):

If it's going to be on Windows 8.1 can you not do it as a Metro/Modern app? The support for multi-touch will be a lot better than it is in WPF I think.

There's some information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh868274) on how you can approach different app categories.

Using the Windows 8 SDK will give you the opportunity to use JavaScript instead of C# if you find that easier too.

Comment: Its a small application with three buttons and 10 pages. I dont know if it will be easier to make that a metro app ?